# Karma unit testing error: Unexpected value imported by the module. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, unit-testing, electron, karma-jasmine, ng-modules

I've created a fresh new component via:

```
ng g mytest1
```

Then I changed the constructor line to this:

```
constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<Mytest1Component>) { }
```

, and added the required import:

```
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
```

After that I ran the Karma unit test project via:

```
ng test
```

The test failed. I got this error message:

> Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[Mytest1Component -> MatDialogRef]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Mytest1Component -> MatDialogRef]: NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!

To fix that I added the Import statement in the beforeEach section:

```
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

//...

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ Mytest1Component ],
        imports: [MatDialogRef],
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

Now I got this new error, which I am not able to fix:

> Failed: Unexpected value 'MatDialogRef' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Can someone clarify where I should be adding the @NgModule annotation, or if I had done something completely wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular error: Please add a @NgModule annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417373/angular-error-please-add-a-ngmodule-annotation)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are injecting `MatDialogRef` in component:

```
constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<Mytest1Component>) { }
```

So the testBed expects the same to be injected as `provider` to the TestBed. Or you can also provide a `MockDialogueService` to it.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ Mytest1Component ],
        providers: [ MatDialogRef ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the first mistake on my part. Now I'm getting another problem, and would appreciate it if you could help out... Is says, "Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for MatDialogRef: (?, ?, ?, ?)."

Comment: Update: I had to follow the recommendation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058457/failed-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-matdialogref-unit-testing-a

Answer (score 5):

use:

```
imports: [MatDialogModule],
```

instead

Comment: Thank you. I got still got the message, "Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[Mytest1Component -> MatDialogRef]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Mytest1Component -> MatDialogRef]: NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!"

Comment: Update: That line was useful. What was still missing was the recommendation made by nircraft: 'providers: [ MatDialogRef ],'
Thank you for the help.